# What does the tag "quality" mean?

Tags: discussion

Well - obviously I understand the english word. But in the context [this post](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10/magnetic-levitation), I dont see any use of it. Maybe there is - but a description would be nice. Or is it some kind of meta-tag for describing "bad quality"?

I think everyone who creates a new tag, should use the tag-wiki to give it a good description. In other cases it is not that difficult to understand, of course. But well defined tags is a must have in the long run.

Answer (score 5):

It's a meta tag - kill it, quickly.

But yes, I agree that everyone who creates a tag, especially one that is not self described by the tag itself, should take the time to create at least a wiki excerpt to explain what the tag should be used for.

Comment: Meta tags describe the question, rather than the subject of the question.  As such I don't think `quality` is a meta tag.  It doesn't seem to be relevant to the question it was used with, certainly.  I do think it's a bad tag that should be killed with fire, though, because "quality" is rather indistinct.  Better to use a tag specific to the metric that we are using to measure quality -- "durability", for example.

Answer (score 3):

It is about quality engineering. I removed it from the [magnetic levitation question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/10/magnetic-levitation) and changed it to [[quality-engineering]](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/quality-engineering) on the [DOE question](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/questions/9/in-aluminum-machining-what-are-the-most-common-factors-that-might-cause-a-machi):

What do you think of my new tag?

I can't edit the wikis, as I don't have [high enough rep](https://engineering.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/trusted-user).

**Updates**

@JohnHK requested refs for Quality Engineering. Here are a couple:

- http://asq.org/pub/qe/ (an ASQ journal)
- http://asq.org/cert/quality-engineer (a certification)
- http://journals.cambridge.org/action/displayJournal?jid=MQE (another journal)

I am not sure what *"mechanical engineering", "chemical engineering" and so forth* means in JohnHK's comment. Does it include Aeronautical Engineering, Requirements Engineering, System Safety and Reliability Engineering, Acoustic Engineering, Systems Engineering, and Hydraulic Engineering ? IMHO, some are minority interests, and some are inter-disciplinary, but most seem relevant to some or other expert practitioners.  Lets tag them if we get questions on them.

Comment: Could you give me a reference for this kind of engineering? The only branch of the applied sciences which is relevant in the engineering context which have to do with 'quality' is 'quality management'. I think we should stay at "mechanical engineering", "chemical engineering" and so forth

Comment: Well, that comment was unprecise. I meant we should use the major fields first, although as you said, it is not well defined what a major field is. As I see it now, you're perfectly right using quality-engineering as a tag, although the name itself seems to be rather underused in the literature. (In contrast to quality management, quality engineer, quality assurance, quality control, ...).